# How to implement a class method to transfer data from user application into the class internal storage

Tags: c++

Consider a `c++` class or `c` struct with functions that implements a certain numerical method, like linear equations system solving. The class may have its own private storage of matrix elements. For precision matters the internal storage may be implemented using the floating type that differs from the application floating type (i.e. application uses `float` but the class uses `long double`).

How should I declare and implement a class method that would transfer any external format data into known internal format data without exposing the internal storage?

EDIT1: I will try to clarify my question a bit: the situation takes place between an API (equation solver, for example) and a client application ("the application"). Of course, the API must be defined before the application will be able to use it. Thus, there must be a class method that allows transfer between known internal type data and unknown external type data. Is it possible to implement that kind of method for unknown type, like it is used in templates?

Comment: Why not just assign it?

Comment: Assign what to what? External to internal? Then question is how would the assignment operator look like?

Comment: I don't get it. Can you give an example of what your external and internal data could look like? You can directly asign a float to a long double and if you have to copy an array of floats to an array of long doubles, you can e.g. use `std::copy`

Comment: Please provide a (code-) example of what you are trying to achieve. I (and others apparently too) really don't understand what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The usual method is `template<typename Iter> void assign(Iter begin, Iter end);`

Comment: So this means that the application must implement the conversion from the external type to the internal type?

Comment: @mbaitoff: Sorry, I have no idea what that question even means. Of course the application has to do it, who else? The OS isn't going to do application tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Either add an assign-method as suggested or overload the **+=** operator to handle any External data that you may feed it.

```
InternalDataClass& operator+=(const ExternalDataSet& rhs)
{
  // ... Convert and Append External Data ...
  return *this;
}
```

Then it is a matter of:

```
ExternalDataSet externalData;
InteranalDataClass idc;
idc+=externalData;
```

Comment: This just shifts the problem into the scope of declaring and implementing the "convert and append" chunk. How do you do it without knowing the external data type? This also introduces binding between the API and the application, which is no good.

Comment: I don't get it, how is it possible to do conversion from arbitrary, unknown set of data? All I can think of then is to pass the data as some bytebuffer and operate on that. Given that you for sure know what the bytebuffer consists of.

Comment: You could expose a struct from your API eg. DataMiddleWareStruct, fill it up in application and let InternalDataClass implement  += operator that is ready to handle that type of data ?